# ag-grid showing a custom overlay

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

Is there a way to show other custom overlays based on program logic?  E.g. I'd like to have an "Error" overlay in addition to "No rows" and "Loading"

I have reviewed and implemented the customized "loading" and "no rows" overlays as described here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlay-component/  Super easy, really clean implementation.

Ideally, the api of showing an overlay could take a parameter that specifies which template to use...

Answer (score 3):

You could have an overlay component which renders the different overlays based on the parameters you send.
You could accomplish this using ngIf in your template and rendering different html based on the parameter.

I don't think there is currently any other way to do it through Ag-Grid.

You can send it parameters for example by doing the following

```
[loadingOverlayComponent]="loadingOverlayComponent"
[loadingOverlayComponentParams]="loadingOverlayComponentParams"


this.loadingOverlayComponent = "customLoadingOverlay";
this.loadingOverlayComponentParams = { template: "overLay1" };
```

and in your component

```
export class CustomLoadingOverlay implements ILoadingOverlayAngularComp {

    private params: any;

    agInit(params): void {
        this.params = params;
      if (params.template == "overLay1") {
            // do something
       }
    }
}
```

I know its not the best way to get this done but that works till we get something implemented into Ag-Grid

Comment: How do you send it parameters?

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: Ok, now how do you set/change the parameters at runtime.

Comment: You can set this.loadingOverlayComponentParams to a function which returns an object based on your needs.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try it and report back soon!  Seems like an overall weakness in the grid API.